# Problems using standard pricebook in unit tests

Tags: unit-test, pricebook

We are running into problems with our unit tests which use the standard pricebook.
When they are run separately they work fine, but as soon as we do a "run all" several tests fail with message:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this
>   record or 1 records: 01s0Y000005PZuEQAW: []

We have been experimenting with the SeeAllData, but either with it on or off it will cause this error. As far as I can see we are not updating the pricebook itself, but we are setting it's Id on our quote / order line items. So maybe it is being updated because of references being added?

Anyone ran in a comparable issue or knows what might be causing this issue?

Comment: I have filed a Idea to remove this lock: [Ability to create multiple PricebookEntry objects for a Pricebook2 in parallel](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cRUiQAM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you have enabled parallel test execution. A fast fix is to disable parallel test execution.

If you want to look deeper, when you set `Id` of this `PriceBook2` to some quote / order line items and update/insert them, that causes to recalculate summary fields on `PriceBook2`. While you have parallel test execution, two or more tests are trying to gain access to this test `Pricebook2` at same time.

There is a [Locking Statements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm) that locks the record via your custom SOQL query, hence you can't apply it to `Pricebook2` in test and the only option for me is to disable parallel test execution.

Comment: Sweet, that solved the problem! This option can be found in Setup -> Apex Test Execution -> Options